# how to show suggestion for UISearchBar search?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uisearchbar, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I am making a demo Weather app, and inside this i am using UISearchBar so can user entry city name, but i don't know how to display suggestion for that.

For example, if user enters "lon" than there should be cities name suggesting start from "lon" like London, etc.

Comment: are you talking about showing the data or view?

Comment: Both. How to retrieve data from a city name list and show it. I want to show this data in TableView but if there is another way it is good.

Comment: as you have search bar, also use searchtableview, you can filter the data as user type and show into table.

Comment: thanks ... but how can i use searchtableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UISearchBar` has its own delegation protocol [`UISearchBarDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchBarDelegate/searchBar:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:), the method -

```
-(BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range
  replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

make possible while editing to do some extra operations, here you can put your `NSPredicate` to see if the inserted text has a city that `BEGINSWITH` or `CONTAINS` the entered text.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by,

1. create an array (List) of places to be shown ... add object in array !

   `NSArray *list;`

   `NSArray *listFiles;`

2.Filter the content ..

```
-(void)filter :(NSString *) match1


    listFiles = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FullName BEGINSWITH[c] %@", match1];

    listFiles = [[ContactDect filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sPredicate ] mutableCopy];
    f_name_array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (NSDictionary *d in listFiles) {

        [self.f_name_array addObject:[d objectForKey:@"FullName"]];

    }
    list=f_name_array;
    NSLog(@"%@",list);



}
```

3. then count list in numberOfRowsInTableview :

`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [listFiles count];
}`

4. cellForRow ::::

`-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"abccell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,[listFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}`

> Call the Filter method while editing textFeild !

```
[self filter:textfeild1.text];
```

I wish it will help you .....

Comment: thanks .... now working .... but how can i get top cities list or i have to type every city name?